# Display query results efficiently in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, datagrid

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application with Visual C# and with the "Razor" option

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Tasks()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Tasks";

        string selectSql = "select * from Tasks";

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=lpc193\adamssqlserver;Database=master;Integrated Security=True;";

        DateTime strt;

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    strt = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Start"));
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

**Tasks.cshtml**

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Tasks To Complete"; 
}

These are the tasks from the table

<!-- some datagrid object here ?? -->
```

**I have the following SQL Server 2012 database table layout**

[image]

I'm able to query the table just fine and pull out each field's value individually.

**What I want to do is** display the result set (with all fields from the select * query) in a DataGridView of sorts to the user.  I could easily place each value into a TR TD and plop that into a string, display it on the .cshtml side... but thats doesn't really teach me anything, and I doubt its very efficient.

**side note** It's extremely difficult to find relevant information regarding Razor and displaying data from a query.  Is it because its new, and/or is Razor something to avoid for a C# novice?

Comment: Pass your data to the model and build your grid dynamically at the client side, by iterating through your model items in Razor view engine. Extract desired values to appropriate cells and that's all. Remember to pass to the client only the data you really want to use. Do not overload the network with redundant information which slows down your page rendering. At best, do not use `select *` at your server side already at retrieving data from database - apply some restriction to shrink data to be fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the fault of the razor view engine, it's more a drawback of the whole ASP.Net MVC thing.

Unlike Webforms, ASP.Net MVC **doesn't offer server-side controls that are automagically converted to HTML**. So basically you will have to build all of your HTML *by hand*.

Of course, there are some built-in classes called **HTML helpers** that will help you with the common HTML stuff (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493063(v=vs.108).aspx).

But there is unfortunately no built-in helper that produces the HTLM for a grid.

You could build your own (yeah, manually write the helper class that'll do all the `td`/`tr` job...) or use existing solutions.
See for example:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx
- http://www.schnieds.com/2010/01/gridview-in-aspnet-mvc.html
- http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html